# SQL Server 2000 Backups Not Writing to Local Disk

Tags: backup, sql-server

I have several databases on a server. This is the only database backup that fails.

It fails from maintenance plans (full backup and transaction log backups)

It fails from T-SQL BACKUP commands.

Here is what ERRORLOG says:

```
  2009-12-04 06:00:41.03 spid57    Internal I/O request 0x6F21C9C0: Op: Write, pBuffer: 0x05670000, Size: 983040, Position: 112919040, UMS: Internal: 0x103, InternalHigh: 0x0, Offset: 0x6BB0200, OffsetHigh: 0x0, m_buf: 0x05670000, m_len: 983040, m_actualBytes: 0, m_errcode: 2, BackupFile: d:\SQLData\MSSQL\BACKUP\DBName\DBName_tlog_200912040600.TRN
  2009-12-04 06:00:41.03 backup    BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP LOG [DBName] TO  DISK = N'd:\SQLData\MSSQL\BACKUP\DBName\DBName_tlog_200912040600.TRN' WITH  INIT ,  NOUNLOAD ,  NOSKIP ,  STATS = 10,  NOFORMAT
```

I can write the database backup to a UNC path off the server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/758718-backup-sql-server-failures.html) had a similar error, which ended up being a disk in the RAID array starting to die.  This would align to the fact that you can backup elsewhere, but not to the physical disk.  Anything in your event logs indicating disk failure?   Does [chkdsk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755829(WS.10).aspx) find anything (the /r parameter will search for bad sectors, but would require the volume to be locked during the scan)? In SQL Server 2005, you would get an Event 823 or 824 if it was hitting checksum errors when writing to the I/O Subsystem, but that doesn't help you with SQL Server 2000 :)